# Cross-compiling the POCO library for OpenWRT Linux environment using the OpenWRT toolchain

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, poco, openwrt

I am trying to cross compile the POCO source package for OpenWRT Linux environment using the OpenWRT toolchain. I have downloaded the POCO source package and am trying to cross compile it, but I am getting the error log as below

```
src/Error.cpp: In static member function 'static std::string
Poco::Error::getMessage(int)': src/Error.cpp:71:55: error: invalid
conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
return std::string(strerror_r(errorCode, errmsg, 256));
                                                       ^
In file included from
/home/ubuntu/subhendu/options_cg/trunk/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.8-linaro_musl-1.1.10/mips-openwrt-linux-musl/include/c++/4.8.3/string:53:0,
                 from include/Poco/Bugcheck.h:24,
                 from include/Poco/Foundation.h:148,
                 from src/Error.cpp:17: /home/ubuntu/subhendu/options_cg/trunk/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.8-linaro_musl-1.1.10/mips-openwrt-linux-musl/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/basic_string.tcc:212:5:
error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT,
_Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' [-fpermissive]
     basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::
     ^
/home/ubuntu/subhendu/Poco/poco-1.6.0/build/rules/compile:53: recipe for target
'/home/ubuntu/subhendu/Poco/poco-1.6.0/Foundation/obj/Linux/x86_64/debug_shared/Error.o'
failed make[1]: ***
[/home/ubuntu/subhendu/Poco/poco-1.6.0/Foundation/obj/Linux/x86_64/debug_shared/Error.o]
Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory
'/home/ubuntu/subhendu/Poco/poco-1.6.0/Foundation' Makefile:69: recipe
for target 'Foundation-libexec' failed make: *** [Foundation-libexec]
Error 2
```

If anybody faced the same issue or has any idea on how to resolve it, please give your solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the man page for strerror_r](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror_r), I see:

```
int strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);
            /* XSI-compliant */
char *strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);
            /* GNU-specific */
```

Note the difference in return type.

Looking at your error message:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
return std::string(strerror_r(errorCode, errmsg, 256));
                                                       ^
```

It seems that the source you're compiling is *expecting* the GNU-specific version of `strerror_r`, but *getting* the XSI-compliant one. Either your target does not *provide* the GNU extension, or your toolchain is not set up correctly.

The man page goes on:

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):
>   The XSI-compliant version of strerror_r() is provided if:
>
> `(_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600) && ! _GNU_SOURCE`
>
> Otherwise, the GNU-specific version is provided.

So you might want to investigate in that direction. (What is `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`, `_XOPEN_SOURCE` and `_GNU_SOURCE` set to when you're trying to compile?)

Comment: @wifiapidev: You're welcome. Actually this is my favourite kind of question -- never used that function, don't know the package in question even by name, don't have the environment to recreate the issue, but still come up with something helpful. ;-)